# GZIP Compression on Tomcat of .svg files

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, gzip, tomcat8

I have a web page running on AWS EC2 Elastic Beanstalk. Running Googles Page Insights, I get the following report:
[image]

As you can see, it's suggesting I add compression. However, I have added compression based on [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html) advise. I added a `.ebextensions/tomcat-settings.config` file containing:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions:
    Xms: 512m
    Xmx: 512m
    JVM Options: '-Xmn128m'
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    API_ENDPOINT: mywebapi.zkpexsjtmd.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:
    GzipCompression: 'true'
    ProxyServer: nginx
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /pub: public
```

From [here](http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/?url=d3d3LnRoZXdob3pvby5jb20=), I can see that compression is applied:

[image]

Before I added the `.ebextensions/tomcat-settings.config` file, no compression was applied. And Google Page Insights also highlighted `.png` files that needed compression too. Now it looks like it's just `.svg` files that need compression.

**Question**

Can anyone please advise how I can also compress the `.svg` files?

Thanks